# openReport action in MS Access with where condition

Tags: jquery, ms-access, userform

I am fairly new to Access and do not have much knowledge with SQL queries.
i have a simple ms access form with two 3 textbox:

txtStartDate,
txtEndDate,
cmbAdvNam,

on click of a command button it performs openReport action and it has a where clause "[Mau_con]![Action Date]>=[Forms]![frmReportFilter]![txtStartDate] AND [Mau_con]![Action Date]<=[Forms]![frmReportFilter]![txtEndDate]"

it is not generating the data, whereas if I use the first clause only (which is before AND) then it generates data in report.

what is the correct query to run this ?

I want to excute another query with this where data will be fetched only for advisor's name matching the name column in table, is there any good tutorial or article which can teach me how to do this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
"[Mau_con]![Action Date] Between DateValue([Forms]![frmReportFilter]![txtStartDate]) And DateValue([Forms]![frmReportFilter]![txtEndDate])"
```

or:

```
"([Mau_con]![Action Date] Between DateValue([Forms]![frmReportFilter]![txtStartDate]) And DateValue([Forms]![frmReportFilter]![txtEndDate])) And ([Mau_con]![Advisor Name] = [Forms]![frmReportFilter]![cmbAdvNam])"
```

Comment: thanks @gustav, but this code is not working as it gives error number 2950

Comment: thanks @gustav, its working now, how to filter with 3rd column as well